# Linq with join query returning only one record

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

Been trying to solve this issue for the past couple of days and it is really frustrating me.  I am only getting a single record displayed inside the `GridView`.

Below is the LINQ code I am using:

```
public IQueryable GetSubCatWithCatName()
    {
        return 
            (from sc in this.Entities.SubCategory
                join c in this.Entities.Category
                on sc.CategoryID equals c.ID

                select new
                {
                    sc.ID,
                    CategoryName = c.Name,

                    SubCategoryName = sc.Name,
                    SubCategoryImage = sc.ImageURL
                });
    }
```

I am displaying the results in a `GridView` component, however only the first record is getting displayed

I have tried a few other versions of the above code to no avail.

Would anyone please help ?

Below is how my `GridView` is defined, if it could be of any help.

```
<asp:GridView ID="gvSubCategories" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        onrowdatabound="gvSubCategories_RowDataBound" 
        onselectedindexchanged="gvSubCategories_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgSubCategory" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Category Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategoryName" HeaderText="Sub Category Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategoryImage" HeaderText="Sub Category Image" />
        </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

In .cs Class

```
gvSubCategories.DataSource = new BASubCategory().GetSubCatWithCatName();
gvSubCategories.DataBind();
```

In BASubCategories

```
    public IQueryable GetSubCatWithCatName()
    {
        return new DASubCategory(this.Entities).GetSubCatWithCatName();
    }
```

In DASubCategories

```
public IQueryable GetSubCatWithCatName()
{
    return 
        (from sc in this.Entities.SubCategory
            join c in this.Entities.Category
            on sc.CategoryID equals c.ID

            select new
            {
                sc.ID,
                CategoryName = c.Name,

                SubCategoryName = sc.Name,
                SubCategoryImage = sc.ImageURL
            });
}
```

in RowDataBound

```
protected void gvSubCategories_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            SubCategory currentSubCat = (SubCategory)e.Row.DataItem;

            //Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("imgSubCategory");
            //img.ImageUrl = currentSubCat.ImageURL;
        }
    }
```

Comment: What does the output of GetSubCatWithCatName look like? Do the missing rows exist in the result of the Linq query?

Comment: I am not sure how to check that

Comment: Set a Breakpoint at the line that calls the method, debug the application, when execution reaches the breakpoint check the result of the call e.g. by moving the mouse over the variable that receives the result.

Comment: Can you show the code that sets the DataSource of the GridView?

Comment: Updated the main question

Comment: When I remove the `join` and select data from only one table, all of the records show.

Comment: What's in your `gvSubCategories_RowDataBound` method?

Comment: Updated the main post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the comments on the other version of your [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20556509/gridview-displaying-only-first-retrieved-record), the OnRowDatabound handler seems to be problematic. Your Linq query returns a dynamic object. In the handler, you cast it to an object of type Subcategory. This will fail - though I can't explain why this ends in only the first record to be shown. Might be related to a page-level or global error handler that swallows the error. Effect seems to be that the GridView stops binding after the first row has triggered the error.
In order to solve this, I'd suggest to create a class that contains the properties that you want to return from your Linq query and that you need in your GrifView and OnRowDatabound handler. In the handler, cast to this type and use the data as required.

Comment: I figured out the same thing a couple of minutes ago.  Thank you; this has solved my problem :)

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest you do a `ToList()` on your data source. I'm not sure if this is the problem you're encountering, but sometimes for an `IEnumerable<>`, if some of the dependencies are disposed before the enumeration occurs, that can prevent it from fully executing. For example, if `this.Entities` become invalid before the page renders, that could cause issues. So do this:

```
gvSubCategories.DataSource = new BASubCategory().GetSubCatWithCatName().ToList();
gvSubCategories.DataBind();
```

Comment: I am using `IQueryable`, cannot use the `ToList()` as you suggested with it.

Comment: `IQueryable<>` is a sub-interface of `IEnumerable<>`. ToList will still work. Make sure you have a `using System.Linq;`

Comment: `Error 3 'System.Linq.IQueryable' does not contain a definition for 'ToList' and no extension method 'ToList' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) 
`

Comment: I have the `using System.Linq`

Comment: Oh... you have the non-generic IQueryable. You could do `.Cast<object>().ToList()` to get an `IList<object>` at least.

Comment: Now my GridView completely disappeared haha.  Something, or someone must really hate me.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. Do you see the data you expect in `DataSource` after assigning the list?

Comment: Yes, the method returns all the values that I need, but the grid view displays only the first.

Comment: I mean with my suggested change... you said the grid completely disappeared. Is the data present and it's still disappearing?

Comment: Yes the data is present