# GridView displaying only first retrieved record

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I am successfully retrieving all the records I need from my database, however only one record is getting displayed in my `GridView`.

I've been trying to solve this for the past couple of days, and I am really getting frustrated  since I ran out of options to try.  I am desperately in need of some help.

I've tried to manipulate the query because I originally thought that it was the problem, tried to convert the data I retrieve from `IQueryable` to `List<MyObject>()`, tried to add `.Cast<object>().ToList();` at the end of the `GridView.DataSource`, and even tried the use of `ViewState`s, and much much more!

Please, anyone, help.

I do have `onRowDataBound` and on `selectedIndexChanged` events for the `GridView` because I read that they can cause this issue.

Below is my code:

**GridView**:

```
gvSubCategories.DataSource = new BASubCategory().GetSubCatWithCatName();
gvSubCategories.DataBind();


protected void gvSubCategories_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        SubCategory currentSubCat = (SubCategory)e.Row.DataItem;

        //Image img = (Image)e.Row.FindControl("imgSubCategory");
        //img.ImageUrl = currentSubCat.ImageURL;
    }
}

protected void gvSubCategories_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    BASubCategory baSubCat = new BASubCategory();
    Guid id = new Guid(gvSubCategories.SelectedDataKey.Value.ToString());
    SubCategory subCat = baSubCat.GetSubCategory(id);

    txtName.Text = subCat.Name;
    imgImage.ImageUrl = subCat.ImageURL;
}
```

**GridView Definition**

```
<div class="content">

    <asp:GridView ID="gvSubCategories" runat="server" DataKeyNames="ID" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
        onrowdatabound="gvSubCategories_RowDataBound" 
        onselectedindexchanged="gvSubCategories_SelectedIndexChanged">
        <Columns>
            <asp:CommandField ShowSelectButton="true" />
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Image ID="imgSubCategory" runat="server" Width="100px" Height="100px" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="CategoryName" HeaderText="Category Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategoryName" HeaderText="Sub Category Name" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="SubCategoryImage" HeaderText="Sub Category Image" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried breaking out the list into its own object and then doing the databind? This would also allow you to check the COUNT on it and make sure that you actually have the records you expect in there

Comment: possible duplicate of [Linq with join query returning only one record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20554853/linq-with-join-query-returning-only-one-record)

Comment: @JimBeam  Yes I have done that before.  I do get the records. I've just tried to comment out `onRowDataBound()` and all the records show.

Answer (score 0):

I've solved this problem myself.

Since the `GridView`'s `RowDataBound` event was declared, and my object per row was made up of two different `Entities` (SubCategory and Category), an error was being generated at the

```
       SubCategory currentSubCat = (SubCategory)e.Row.DataItem;
```

of the mentioned event.  It couldn't convert an Anonymous object (made up of both SubCategory and Category) to a `SubCategory`, thus firing the exception.  This caused the `GridView` to stop executing the `RowDataBound` after the first element was placed, thus displaying only the first element.

I had to remove the line above and everything worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Just to put my answer out there for this issue.  I had a gridview column which looked like this:

```html
<asp:BoundField DataField="DueDate" HeaderText="DueDate" SortExpression="DueDate">
  <ItemStyle Wrap="False" />
</asp:BoundField>
```

My grid was being field in the code behind calling a stored procedure, not too much to see here either.  The end of the c# looked like this

```
gv_maingrid2.DataSource = dt
gv_maingrid2.DataBind()
```

The problem was that my stored procedure did not return a column header for the DueDate column.  When I ran the stored procedure in SSMS, the DueDate column value displayed "(No Column Name)" because I was casting the value to a varchar and never added the alias or column name.  Check to see you're getting all of you column headers.  I hope this helps someone!!